# Create exe application Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, exe

I would like to create a `Visual Studio` project that provides an `exe` file
(like `winform` or `console application`) and does not have user inteface.

Is there any kind of such a project?

Comment: You could do a Console Application and run it as a service.

Comment: You can also create a Windows service which is an application with no user interaction and runs in the background.  Users don't even have to be logged on to the machine for it to run.

Comment: Create a console application and then change its type to Windows application.

Comment: @HaukurHaf, Sounds great. How can I create such a service?

Comment: @user3165438, from the "New project" Window, just select "Windows desktop" and from the list on the right, select "Windows Service".  Note that writing a service is a bit different from writing a regular Windows application.  I recommend this walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: -1: the question is unclear, and shows no research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a Console Application project type when you go to `New -> Project`. Depending on which language you'll be writing in, it may be in a different category (on the left hand side of the New Project screen)

Comment: Thanks, but Console Application execute the command line. Isn't it? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Three simple steps:

1. Create a new *Console Application*: [image: Create a console application]
2. In the solution explorer, select the project, open the context menu and choose “Properties” to open the project properties: [image: Open project properties]
3. In the project properties, change the “Output Type” to “Windows Application”: [image: Change project output type]

Afterwards, your program—when launched—will run without creating a console and without creating any other visible windows. Note that this will also—obviously—prevent you from interacting with it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to register your program as a service?

Here is walkthrough how to do that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a WinForms application and pass a class which inherits from ApplicationContext (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) to the Application.Run() method in your Program.cs file. this class can then execute whatever else you want without displaying any UI to the user.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new ClassWhichInheritsFromApplicationContext());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and when I run it, there will be no UI?

Comment: Aye. The object which gets passed to Application.Run() won't initialize any UI components (which is what new Form() would normally do there)